# Error Searching a List when Using TCL Interactively

Tags: list, search, tcl, interactive

I'm running a Cisco Nexus 5548Up with Cisco OS version 7.0.5(N1)1.  This comes with an TCL interpreter, version 8.5.7, that I'm using interactively, but getting results I don't understand nor know how to correct.

```
set VLAN_MATCH_LIST {}
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 102
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 122
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 232
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 242
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 243
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 246
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 259
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 283
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 286
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 288
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 334
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 341
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 346
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 356
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 358
lappend VLAN_MATCH_LIST 373

puts "List: $VLAN_MATCH_LIST"
puts "Found item 122 at index [lsearch VLAN_MATCH_LIST 122]"
```

Unfortunately, I'm expecting to find "122" at index 1, but I keep getting this output (last 2 lines only):

```
List: 102 122 232 242 243 246 259 283 286 288 334 341 346 356 358 373
Found item 122 at index -1
```

If you're wondering, I do all the lappend stuff instead of using the `set` command on account of wanting to make sure the issue isn't related to my variable initialization syntax, but rather something more substantive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the name of the variable to `lsearch`, not the list value contained in that variable. You need to dereference the name by prefixing it with `$`:

```
puts "Found item 122 at index [lsearch $VLAN_MATCH_LIST 122]"
```

Tcl cares a lot about the difference between the names of variables and their contents. Some Tcl commands take the names of variables (both `set` and `lappend` in your script are like this); this is typically because they are updating the variable. Values themselves are logically read-only (the implementation is smarter than that, but that's not something you should think about for now).

Comment: Gotcha.  Appreciate the training!

Answer (score 1):

Reference to the list variable should be with `$` sign. Try yo use `[lsearch $VLAN_MATCH_LIST 122]` instead. Also, the default list matching rule is `-glob`. Is will not cause errors in your case, but it is good practice to use the `-exact` matching rule if you expect it.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you; that fixed it exactly.